# Instead of dragging a stored procedure, can I just cut and paste its name somewhere?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I am using LINQ to SQL, and there is one thing I am not very happy about.

Suppose I don't have a stored procedure I need, so I just go ahead and develop a new one. Now I want to expose it via the LINQ to SQL `DataContext`, so I have to:

1. refresh the list of stored procs, which takes a few seconds
2. Find the new stored procedure in this list, which also uses up precious time - I have thousands of them to scroll through.

Is there any way I could just open up a dialog and paste the stored procedure name - that should be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can always edit the DBML by hand if you like. Otherwise, no; the tooling is "as is". Since most development effort by MS is on EF, we shouldn't expect it to improve much /soon / possibly-ever.